# Creating a table of barcodes using JSBarcode

Tags: node.js, ejs, jsbarcode

I am trying to create a table of unique barcodes using node, bootstrap, and ejs. Here are the contents of my `.ejs` file:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.4/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Employee</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% employeeObj.forEach(function(obj) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= obj.id %><svg id="barcode"></svg><script>var employee = '<%= obj.id %>'; JsBarcode("#barcode", employee);</script></td>
                </tr>
                <% }); %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason in each row of the table the barcode is being generated, but every barcode is the exact same value. I tried just putting the string value of `obj.id` in each row and it displays the different values fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my issue was that the `id` for every barcode was the same which resulted in the same barcode being display multiple times. The solution to this problem is to have a unique `id` which could be accomplished like this:

```
id="<%=obj.id%>"
```